# WebPack module build error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sails.js, babeljs

Having trouble with building react project with WebPack.

Getting the following error output, is there a way to get a more info out of web pack on this issue.

running: `webpack --display-error-details --display-reasons --progress -p --config  webpack.config.prod.js`

```
62% 478/543 build modulesError
at NormalModule.<anonymous> (...../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:113:20)
at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (..../node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
at nextLoader (..../node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
at ...node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
at Storage.finished (....node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
at .../node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:438:3)
```

69% 1917/1919 build modules